# Fetch and display json object from api in the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, typescript

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export default function Aapi() {
  const [record, setRecords] = useState([]);
  var arr = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=93ogbcdhee0a74")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((jsonResponse) => {
        arr.push(jsonResponse.city, jsonResponse.country);
        setRecords(arr);
        console.log(arr);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {Array.isArray(record) ? (
        record.map((records) => {
          return (
            <div key={uuidv4()}>
              <p>{records.city + "+ "}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <p>null</p>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the code ,
I am using an API from which I am fetching the json object and converting it array so as to use map function to display in my project as map function works on the array elements. It successfully gives output in console as array but I am not able to display it on the project.
If there is any error please mention it or any alternative to display json object (**not array**) in projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to push array element as object. Currently you are pushing directly as values.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=93ogbcdhee0a74")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((jsonResponse) => {
        arr.push({
          "city": jsonResponse.city, 
          "country": jsonResponse.country
        });
        setRecords(arr);
        console.log(arr);
      });
  }, []);
```

Add `city` and `country` as keys since you are accessing them to render.

```
return (
    <div key={uuidv4()}>
        <p>{records.city + "+ "}</p>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Yup got my mistake :(  @RaviYadav Thankyou for the solution and your time    : |) This works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export default function Aapi() {
  const [record, setRecords] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=93ogbcdhee0a74")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((jsonResponse) => {
        setRecords(jsonResponse);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {record.city && record.country ? (
        <div key={uuidv4()}>
          <p>City: {record.city}</p>
          <p>Country: {record.country}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>null</p>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```